# How class call other class function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class

I am new to react and javascript. May I know how to call other class function from current class?

I only able to use prop to pass the data between class.

For example, I have one toolbar and one user class. When I click the toolbar delete button. I want to call delete function in my user class. How to achieve this?

So this is my toolbar. When I click delete button,I want to trigger deleteUser in my user class.

```
let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
const { numSelected, classes, selectedArray } = props;
  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Typography color="inherit" variant="subtitle1">
            {numSelected} selected
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
            User List
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.spacer} />
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Tooltip title="Delete">
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete '+numSelected +' item?')) deleteUser() } }>

              </DeleteIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
              <FilterListIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  selectedArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

EnhancedTableToolbar = withStyles(toolbarStyles)(EnhancedTableToolbar);
```

This is my user class. The toolbar is used in this class. I want the deleteUser() get triggered when the toolbar delete button is clicked.

```
class User extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = initialState;
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
          }

    reset() {
        this.setState(initialState);
    }   

    componentDidMount() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:4000/readUsers")
              .then(json => {
                this.setState({data: json.data});
                console.log({json})
              }).catch(err => console.log("error:   "+err));
    }

    deleteUser(){

    }


    displayUsers(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { data, order, orderBy, selected, rowsPerPage, page } = this.state;
        const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, data.length - page * rowsPerPage);
        console.log("selected length:  "+selected.length+" selected:  "+selected);
        return(
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} selectedArray={selected} />
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                        {n.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.name}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.username}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.email}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.address}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );

                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={data.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Next Page',
          }}
          onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      );
  } 

  handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
      order = 'asc';
    }

    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
  };

  handleSelectAllClick = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState(state => ({ selected: state.data.map(n => n.id) }));
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  };

  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };

  handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
    this.setState({ page });
  };

  handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    this.setState({ rowsPerPage: event.target.value });
  };

  isSelected = id => this.state.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

  render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
    <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
            {this.checkCurrentButton()}
            <Card>
            <CardHeader color="primary">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>User List</h4>
                <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                {}
                </p>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
            {this.displayUser()}
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>

            </CardFooter>
            </Card>
            </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>

    );
  }
}

User.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the function as a prop to the toolbar from your parent class and then access it like any other prop with this.props.deleteUser() like so:

```
let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
const { numSelected, classes, selectedArray } = props;
  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Typography color="inherit" variant="subtitle1">
            {numSelected} selected
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
            User List
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.spacer} />
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Tooltip title="Delete">
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete '+numSelected +' item?')) this.props.deleteUser() } }>

              </DeleteIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
              <FilterListIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  selectedArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

EnhancedTableToolbar = withStyles(toolbarStyles)(EnhancedTableToolbar);
```

And your User Class:

```
class User extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = initialState;
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
          }

    reset() {
        this.setState(initialState);
    }   

    componentDidMount() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:4000/readUsers")
              .then(json => {
                this.setState({data: json.data});
                console.log({json})
              }).catch(err => console.log("error:   "+err));
    }

    deleteUser(){

    }


    displayUsers(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { data, order, orderBy, selected, rowsPerPage, page } = this.state;
        const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, data.length - page * rowsPerPage);
        console.log("selected length:  "+selected.length+" selected:  "+selected);
        return(
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar deleteUser={this.deleteUser} numSelected={selected.length} selectedArray={selected} />
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                        {n.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.name}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.username}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.email}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.address}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );

                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={data.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Next Page',
          }}
          onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      );
  } 

  handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
      order = 'asc';
    }

    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
  };

  handleSelectAllClick = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState(state => ({ selected: state.data.map(n => n.id) }));
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  };

  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };

  handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
    this.setState({ page });
  };

  handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    this.setState({ rowsPerPage: event.target.value });
  };

  isSelected = id => this.state.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

  render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
    <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
            {this.checkCurrentButton()}
            <Card>
            <CardHeader color="primary">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>User List</h4>
                <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                {}
                </p>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
            {this.displayUser()}
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>

            </CardFooter>
            </Card>
            </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>

    );
  }
}

User.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `deleteUser` function from your parent component to the child component. You can do this in the props. You're calling the `EnhancedTableToolbar` inside of the `displayUsers` method, so in it do the following:

```
 return(
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <EnhancedTableToolbar 
            numSelected={selected.length} 
            selectedArray={selected}
            deleteUser={this.deleteUser} // you pass the deleteUser of the parent component to the EnhancedTableToolbar as a prop
    />
```

Then use it inside of the `EnhancedTableToolbar`

```
<IconButton aria-label="Delete">
 <DeleteIcon onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete '+numSelected +' item?')) this.props.deleteUser() } }>
</DeleteIcon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Toolbar component has to receive a property such as *onDeleteUser*

This way the parent can give the Toolbar a way for it to “call back” when something such as a click happened.

So Toolbar will do something like onClick={this.props.onDeleteUser}
When someone clicks and that event fires, the function is called and the Parent can delete the user.